# Regex used by Music Application

Tags: release-loki, music

i've seen that Music application search a specific music in using the Album. (in the expression)

But, it's possible to search a music by the title ?

Thx for read this post.

Answer (score 1):

In the search field of noise you can search either by artist, album or title (or any other field). However, I there is no support for regular expressions.
I hope this answers you question.